# How to separate custom Close Button from Window_Closing?

Tags: c#, wpf, forms

I'm building the WPF app with multiple forms, and my goal is that, on, let's say LoginForm I have a button called Login, which, when clicked, closes current form (LoginForm from above) and opens another form (let's say Form1).

Note that I'm trying to have only one form opened at a time.

Code -

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(everything okay)
        {
            Form1 frm = new Form1();
            frm.Show();
            Close();
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }
```

This works fine. But, my second idea is that, if X in the top right corner is clicked, I want to close this form, and not to open any other, basically exiting the app.

Code-

```
private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBoxResult rez = MessageBox.Show("Do you wish to leave the app?", "Question?", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question);

        if (rez != MessageBoxResult.Yes)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

This is where my problem starts, I've found that Window_Closing and this.Close() are same event, so, when I click the Login button, MessageBoxResult still shows up, even tho that is not my goal. **I want to somehow separate those two events, if that is possible. How can I do so?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could temporarily unhook the event handler just before you call `Close()`:

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (everything okay)
    {
        Form1 frm = new Form1();
        frm.Show();
        Closing -= Window_Closing;
        Close();
        Closing += Window_Closing;
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

Or use a `bool` variable to determine whether to display the `MessageBox`:

```
private bool _showMessageBox = true;

private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (everything okay)
    {
        Form1 frm = new Form1();
        frm.Show();
        _showMessageBox = false;
        Close();
        _showMessageBox = true;
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
}

private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (!_showMessageBox)
        return;

    MessageBoxResult rez = MessageBox.Show("Do you wish to leave the app?", "Question?", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question);

    if (rez != MessageBoxResult.Yes)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this.Close is not a event. this.Close() is a method and after that the event Window_Closing is raised

Try something like that:

```
Form1 frm = new Form1();
Hide();
frm.ShowDialog();
Close();
```

you create a form, then you hide the login form and then you show the Dialog of the form. The Close will then be raised after the new Form1() is closed.

Comment: You are right regarding the methods, but your code is not doing what I need. I still get the message, after exiting other form. Update - It works if you remove Close(); but I still think that there is a better solution.

Comment: If you share more of your code it will be easier to understand the problem and give you a suitable solution =)

Comment: i think the best solution is when you call your main Form and from this you will raise the LoginForm. If Success -> Close Login and everything is OK.... if False -> Close Application